# Symfony: Dynamic configuration file loading

Tags: symfony, configuration

Here is the context :

- Each user of my application belongs to a company.
- Parameters for each company are defined inside "company.yml" configuration files, all of them sharing the exact same structure.
- These parameters are then used to tweak the application behavior.

It may sound trivial, but all I'm looking for is the proper way to load these specific YAML files.

---

From what I understood so far, using an Extension class isn't possible, since it has no knowledge about current user.

Using a custom service to manage these configurations rather than relying on Symfony's parameters seems more appropriate, but I can't find how to implement validation (using a Configuration class) and caching.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Yaml, Processor and Configuration components of Symfony2 should fit your needs.

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html

Define your "CompanyConfiguration" class as if you were in the DependencyInjection case
Create a new "CompanyLoader" service

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor;

$companies = Yaml::parse('company.yml');
$processor = new Processor();
$configuration = new CompanyConfiguration();
$processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $companies);
```

Now you should be able to use your companies array to do what you want

Comment: This Processor instance might be what I've been looking for, I'll definitely try this, thanks! :)

Comment: I just finished implementing this solution, and it works like a charm. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/configuration_organization.html as well as http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html. If that's not the correct answer you'll have to be more specific on what your company.yml configuration contains.

Comment: Most if not all Symfony's documentation on the subject (including these links) is about _global_ application configuration, while I need to work on request level.

To give you an example:
- Company A needs access to a statistic page.
- Company B wants it too, but with more information.
- Company C doesn't need it at all.
Using a configuration file per company, I can manage these differences without hardcoding anything.
I can't rely on a global and static configuration though, and need to load the corresponding file depending on current user's company.

Comment: so you don't have one yml per company but many? because if it's only one per company i'd speak about a "global" config - and you could have one prod-env per company which is then loading only the yml which you require - again using the links provided.

Comment: Got it. That's a different and interesting approach that I'll have to try on my spare time :) Since the service container seems available in AppKernel, I should be able to access the current user and then load the corresponding conf file.
Thanks for your input!