# registerContainerConfiguration do not execute in Prod

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, kernel

i would like to load a yml file in same time that the config.yml.
this is my code:

`public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
        $envParameters = $this->getEnvParameters();
        if(isset($envParameters['config.boutique'])){
            $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/boutique/'.$envParameters['config.boutique'].'.yml');
        }
    }`

in mode dev, this work like a charm but when i am in mode prod, this function do not execute.
i have to replace this line in app.dev.php :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

by

`$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);`

how can i to load this yml file in mode prod?
thanks for your help

Comment: did you clear the cache with --env=prod argument?

Comment: yes, i tried too.in mode prod the function "registerContainerConfiguration" which declared in appkernel.php  is not execute.it's very strange!!

Comment: I have no idea. Is it a problem to just import your config file in config_xxx.yml?

Comment: yes because the loaded file depends on an environment variable.

Comment: If I understand right, in prod config_prod.yml load a parameter wich define the boutique file? and config_dev.yml load the same parameter with a different value?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you can't define a parameter in the config file and use it already because symfony has to compile its kernel.

You can define the file by putting

```
#config_prod.yml
   imports:
    - { resource: boutique/YOUR_VALUE.yml }
#config_dev.yml
   imports:
    - { resource: boutique/YOUR_VALUE_DEV.yml }
```

If the `YOUR_VALUE` is dynamic I hope this post will help: [Symfony: Dynamic configuration file loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586561/symfony-dynamic-configuration-file-loading) . It is using  `DependencyInjection` of the Bundle